Dynamic Grid Borders and “Carved” Effect for a Puzzle Game
I'm working on a 2D puzzle game in Unity, which essentially consists of a grid of pieces. I'm unsure about how to achieve two things:
Dynamic Borders: I aim to add borders around the non-empty parts of the grid. Empty parts can be on the outer edges or within the grid. I want to make these borders dynamically adjust as the grid changes, with curved edges. Does anyone have suggestions on how to implement this, maybe using LineRenderer or another something?
Carved Effect for Pieces: I also want to give the grid a "carved-in" appearance to make it seem more 3D, with a carved-in effect for occupied spaces and a carved-out effect for empty ones. Again, I'm uncertain about the best approach.
Here's an example that illustrates quite well what I want to achieve, except that the grid is carved out (but I'm guessing achieving it is similar): https://i.pinimg.com/originals/da/79/e6/da79e66967a2205e8a2363d6207ae25a.gif
I'm a newbie so any tips or resources to achieve these effects are welcomed. Cheers!

It depends how beautiful and customizable you want the grid to be. If you want to copy the appearance as on the gif, you can simply draw every cell with a sprite with all 4 corners rounded, and then if you have neighbor cells you add "filling" sprite of the same color to fill the gaps
